# Redirecting using ARR 400.0 error

Tags: tomcat, iis-8.5, arr

I have installed ARR 2.5 + hotfix on IIS 8.5, and I wanted to redirect requests coming to IIS to my Tomcat web application (Example localhost/test). I created rules and it worked successfully, but I'm implementing SSO on this webapp, so I need to show the login page first then redirect to my app when it's successful. For the sso I have 3 folders(one,two,three) and I added rules not to rewrite nor redirect to tomcat and it worked, but when ever I sign in using my credentials I'm getting error 400.0 saying that I have reached max forward limits.. I googled that and the suggestion I'm having is to change port? But I'm not using servers farm I'm just using the default website to point to my web app and to the SSO folders.

Any idea?